# How to use an if statement to modify output in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a [toy database](https://github.com/dominiquealpinski/sql) containing information on movies/actors/roles/etc.. to learn SQL.

The function below uses two select statements to populate a final output which shows i) an actor's name (year born - year died), and ii) their filmography.

That information is selected using a matching function (using ilike) based on the actor's name. When it returns a distinct name the function works as intended.

But sometimes first function returns no results, and sometimes more than one distinct actor's name is returned from the matching function. I would like to insert an if-statement to allow for these outcomes (returning a message: 'No matching name' or 'Ambiguous name') before stopping.  But I'm unsure about how to go about it.

My attempt at the if-statement starts after the initial select statement.
Current PL\pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo_slow(_pattern text) 
  RETURNS table (info text) --<< define the output structure
AS $$
DECLARE
  _result record;
BEGIN
  select distinct concat(people.name, ' (', people.year_born, '-', people.year_died, ')') 
    into info --<< store it into the "output column"
  from people
  where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%');
  
--THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO INSERT MY IF STATEMENT TO DEAL WITH CASES WHERE
--ZERO OR > 1 DISTINCT ACTORS NAMES ARE RETURNED FROM THE SELECT STATEMENT ABOVE
   if (select actor_name from q12) is null then
   q12 := 'No matching name';
   exit ;
   elsif (select count(distinct actor_name) from q12) > 1 then
   q12 := 'Ambiguous name';
   exit ;
   END IF;

  return next; ---<< implicitly returns the value of "info"
              
  for _result in
    -- SECOND FUNCTION: returns all films and roles
    select concat(movies.title, ' ', '(', movies.year_made, ')', ' as ', STRING_AGG(plays.character, ',')) as title
    from people
      left join plays on people.id = plays.person_id
      left join movies on plays.movie_id = movies.id
      where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%')
      group by movies.id
   loop
      info := _result.title; --<< store it into the "output column"
      return next; ---<< implicitly returns the value of "info"
   end loop;               
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Include the DDL and DML of the **relevant** objects in the question itself. Do not post any links to repositories. They might go down or change and therefore invalidate the question. Further more they likely include a lot of unrelated things. Include the desired result with the given sample data too. Also see [example].

Comment: I'm just learning SQL and I have no idea how to remove any object that are not relevant to the question from this example and still have it work. The link to the github repo is just FYI, I don't think that the DB dump contained there is necessary to answer the question. For someone well acquainted with SQL, I'd assume questions of basic control flow, like this one, would be fairly straight forward. Happy to be corrected!

Comment: If you wish... Her goes the correction: A [example] helps to convey what you really have and want. It therefore helps to avoid misunderstandings and/or lengthy discussions in comments, which is not how this platform is supposed to be used. So no, it's not just FYI, it's essential. *Sometimes* we can make educated guesses but still it is not considered nice of someone asking to force us to do that. Plus when creating a [example] there's a good chance that in the process you discover the problem's cause and solution yourself.